# MySQL ranking query is not giving expected value

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have the following situation: There is a table that relates wallets and divisions. I have to rank users that are in the same division. The SQL code that I am using is working, but when I try put row numbers it gives strange results. I really tried a lot of different strategies but nothing worked for me.

```
select * , @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
from division_user, 
wallet JOIN   (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
where division_user.division_id in (select division_user.division_id 
                                    from division_user 
                                    where division_user.wallet_id in  
                                            (select wallet.id from wallet where wallet.user_id = 1 )) AND 
division_user.wallet_id = wallet.id 
group by wallet.id 
order by wallet.weekly_profit_value DESC
```

The output of the query is:

```
   1,3
   2,5
   3,1
```

Desired result

```
    1,1
    2,2
    3,3
```

Comment: You may probably need to show your sample data, result from your query and expected result.

Comment: Could you provide us your table structure with sample data ?

Comment: Sorry, tried to put some data... I need a row number... the problem is that the row counting is very strange.

Comment: @RenanGeraldo could you provide us the table structure ? What do you mean with the counting is strange are you using auto increment ?

Comment: It is not about auto increment. I have to rank wallets that are on a same division. I want to enumerate each row.  First player; RowNumber = 1, second player; RowNumber =2... So I used an order by, and the users are listed right but it is like this: FirstPlayer;RowNumber = 2; SecondPlayer: RowNumber = 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and `group by` don't always work together.  Also, *never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `join` syntax.

```
select duw.*, (@curRow := @curRow + 1) AS row_number
from (select du.*, w.*
      from division_user du join 
           wallet w 
           on du.wallet_id = w.id
      where du.division_id in (select du2.division_id 
                               from division_user du2
                               where du2.wallet_id in (select w2.id
                                                       from wallet w2
                                                       where w2.user_id = 1
                                                      )
                              ) 
     group by w.id 
    ) duw cross join
    (SELECT @curRow := 0) params
order by w.weekly_profit_value DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon it worked perfectly. Another doubt: to get just one row with the specific user position, should I just move the (@curRow := @curRow + 1) to the other select?

Comment: @Noob . . . It is archaic syntax.  You should learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax . . . it was introduced into the language decades ago.